# Stop ringtone and audio in Android when listening audio

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am building an Android app for webradio.

I am using [vitamio](http://vov.io/vitamio/) player that extends the functions of the standard MediaPlayer. This problem could also be happening in the standard Media Player as well.

If I'm listening radio and I receive a call, ringtone starts, but the radio doesn't stop!!!

How can I stop it ?

Which event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Otherwise, I think what you are looking for if you are a developer of the said app is provided at [this link](http://mfarhan133.wordpress.com/2010/10/15/manipulating-incoming-ougoing-calls-tutorial-for-android/). It provides an example of hooks that monitor phone state. On the ringing or call active states you can set your app to a paused or silent state.